# How to parse this string format in loop?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

**I have a string response by this format:**

```
[{"error":false,"getFriends":{"name":"iman2420","email":"2420@isa.ir","is_online":"1","status":"one comment aboute me","img":"56f3baaad2f111.89286338"}},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":false,"getFriends":{"name":"amin","email":"2421@isa.ir","is_online":"0","status":"all of new statuse","img":"56f424ba2920e4.32579063"}},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true},{"error":true}]
```

how to parse this string format in loop?

Comment: It's not String it's a Json array.You can do this parsing in many ways. can you please tell me which library are you using to fetch this data

Comment: What have you tried so far? What output are you looking for? Did you do a basic Google search on how to parse JSON Strings (from the tags it is evident that you know it is a json string)? You cannot just come here and ask people to write code for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not expect all men are scientists (like us).

```
        try {
            JSONArray json_Array = new JSONArray(response);
            for (int i=0;i<json_Array.length();i++) {
                 JSONObject json_data = json_Array.getJSONObject(i);
                boolean getFriendsError = json_data.getBoolean("error");
                if (!getFriendsError) {
                 ....
                }else{
                 ....
                }
                                                     }
```

Comment: Yes this is the solution, THANKS ALLOT!